# NGINX - location is overriding root - 404 for any static file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, dns

This is not the best title, but it fits my problem.

I've been trying to place an angular front end and nodejs rest api, under the same domain and in nginx under the same server.

[image]

When i'm trying to access any static files from "/public" without the angular location every thing works, but with the angular i always get 404 not found.

Come someone please help :/
Thanks in advance

First edit -------------------
Add image content in text

```
server { 
listen      80;
server_name subddomain.domain.com;
root /var/www/public/;

location ^~ /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7080;
}
```

}

Comment: Put config as a text, not screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your root location to the following and add `@backend` location :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}

location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7080;
}
```

try_files will try to serve files from `root directive`, if not found it will fall back to `@backend`.

Comment: The static files are working but the angular ain't - "Nginx - 403 Forbidden"

Comment: try_files /nonexistent  @backoffice; http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files